# Razor Pages override route getting RoutePatternException despite seemingly correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages, and everything has been going smoothly so far.

Now I wish to create a page with an override route. Like the override routes that are shown possible  [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes).

I am, however encountering the following exception, despite I don't seem to have the issue in my code that it describes:

```
RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.
```

I must be somehow misunderstanding how this routing works, but I haven't been able to find someone encountering the same issue in my preliminary searches.

This is my entire code on this page so far:

```cs
@page "/layouts/{layoutId:int}/save/{revisionId:int}"
@model Project.Web.Pages.TenantBased.Layouts.SavePageModel
@{
    Layout = "_TenantLayout";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
}
```

And this is the code-behind:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Legalit.Web.Pages.TenantBased.Layouts
{
    public class SavePageModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet(int layoutId, int revisionId)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following exception when running the project:

```
RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.
```

If I remove the first `/` from the route as so:

```cs
@page "layouts/{layoutId:int}/save/{revisionId:int}"
```

Then it stops generating the exception, but I of course get the wrong routing from it. Now my page is reachable by the directory path with this route added to the end of it.

I am using .NET 6.0.
The project type is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`

Comment: Hi @Jonas Kjær, I cannot reproduce your issue and for this error message it is caused by you add extra { or }, I think you need try again and confirm `{}` is correct. Besides, what is the asp.net core version you use? Also, could you pls share your Startup.cs or Program.cs which used to configure the service? And did you configure anything in your backend PageModel?

Comment: @Rena I have added my .NET version and project type. I have also added the code-behind. I will look at the project again when I get some time later today. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: What is your folder structure for pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project had a custom Convention in the `Program.cs` that was specified under the `AddRazorPagesOptions` configuration method.

After removing this, it worked fine.